# why object value is repeating in other object, my json reponse is this

Tags: php, json

foreach ($user_joined_players as $user_joined_player) {

```
            foreach ($batting_live_scores as $batting_live_score) {
                if (in_array($batting_live_score['player_id'], explode(',', $user_joined_player['players_id']))) {
                    $player_data = array();
                    $player_data['player_id'] = $batting_live_score['player_id'];
                    $player_data['one'] = $batting_live_score['one'];
                    $p_data[] = $player_data;
                }
            }
            $user_data['user_name'] = $user_joined_player['fname'];
            $user_data['user_players'] = $p_data;

            $data[] = $user_data;
        }
        $json = array("status" => "success", "data" => $data);
```

{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "user_name": "Harshn",
            "user_players": [
                {
                    "player_id": "2",
                    "one": "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Test",
            "user_players": [
                {
                    "player_id": "2",
                    "one": "2"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "6",
                    "one": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user_name": "NilSan",
            "user_players": [
                {
                    "player_id": "2",
                    "one": "2"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "6",
                    "one": "0"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "1",
                    "one": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user_name": "Raaz",
            "user_players": [
                {
                    "player_id": "2",
                    "one": "2"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "6",
                    "one": "0"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "1",
                    "one": "1"
                },
                {
                    "player_id": "1",
                    "one": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Now is the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($batting_live_scores as $batting_live_score) {
    if (in_array($batting_live_score['player_id'], explode(',', $user_joined_player['players_id']))) {
        $player_data = array();
        $player_data['player_id'] = $batting_live_score['player_id'];
        $player_data['one'] = $batting_live_score['one'];
        $p_data[] = $player_data;
    }
}
```